# Pig Latin query using group by and MAX function

Tags: apache-pig

Given the table:

```
Place(name, province, population, mayorid)
```

How would you write in Pig Latin the following query?
Return for each province the place(s) with the largest population. Your result set should have the province name, the place name and the population of that place.

Comment: As always: What have you tried? This site is not for other people doing your work but to help you solve your problem. You need to read the documentation and try yourself first.

Comment: I already read the documentation ..the problem is that I also have to return the name which means that this should be done with a subquery but i don't know how `B = GROUP place BY province;

X = FOREACH B GENERATE province, MAX(population);`

Comment: Well. *try*. Write it bit by bit, and when you get stuck, ask a question. Include what you want, what you have tried and why it's not working.

Comment: Us geeks no longer do other people's homework either.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this, but something like

```
places = LOAD 'placesInput' AS (name, province, population, mayorid);
placesProjected = FOREACH places GENERATE name,province,population;
placesGrouped = GROUP placesProjected by province;
biggestPlaces = FOREACH placesGrouped {
    sorted = ORDER placesProjected by population DESC;
    maxPopulation = LIMIT sorted 1;
    GENERATE group as province, FLATTEN(maxPopulation.name) as name, FLATTEN(maxPopulation.population) as population;
};
```

oughta work.